# Supervisorctl hangs while restarting process

Tags: supervisord

When `restart <process_name>` is issued on `supervisorctl`, sometimes it restarts the process and prints the messages:

```
transmission:transmission_daemon_9100: stopped
transmission:transmission_daemon_9100: started
```

This is expected behaviour. However, sometimes after the command is issued, `supervisorctl` just hangs and prints nothing even though it successfully restarts the process. Why does it hang and print nothing?